# #Python oserror: [errno 22] invalid argument

Tags: python

```
from subprocess import run as RUN
link = "yt-dlp -f 399 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzH3-8_Y7oo --print filename --encoding utf-8" 
videos = RUN(link, capture_output=True, encoding='utf-8').stdout
print(videos)
```

Above output gives me expected answer
[M⧸V] 김예림(림킴) - Confess To You ：： 킹더랜드(King the Land) OST Part.2 [vzH3-8_Y7oo].mp4

But when I open the file in my directory...

```
with open(videos, 'rb') as f:
    file = f.read()
    print(file)
```

Give me OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '[M⧸V] 김예림(림킴) - Confess To You ：： 킹더랜드(King the Land) OST Part.2 [vzH3-8_Y7oo].mp4\n'

I knew the Error means there might be an invalid character in relative path like '\/:*?"<>|',
but I find out that why there's '\n' after .mp4? "print(video)" does not contain '\n' and my filename either.

I have try:

```
if os.path.exists(f"D:\Youtube vedio project\{videos}"):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

The output is "False" because there's '\n' after .mp4 doesn't match the correct filename

And then, I tried to remove invalid characters and rename the file in directory

```
src_dir = "D:\Youtube vedio project"
def remove_invalid_characters_from_filename(filename):
    invalid_characters = re.compile(r'[\\/:*?"<>|\n]')
    new_filename = invalid_characters.sub('', filename)
    return new_filename
new_filename = remove_invalid_characters_from_filename(videos)
print(new_filename)

os.rename(os.path.join(src_dir, videos), os.path.join(src_dir, new_filename))
```

I can't rename the file and got OSError: [WinError 123]

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] instead of a bunch of snippets that need to be combined?

Comment: Is that your actual `src_dir`?  It's dangerous to use unescaped backslashes in a string, sometimes it works and sometimes it fails drastically.  Raw strings would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\n` represents a line break. I suspect that when you run `print(videos)` in your first snippet, the `\n` gets printed as an actual line break, not its symbolic representation. That's why you can't see it the way you expect.

If I am correct, this should do the trick:

```
with open(videos.rstrip('\n'), 'rb') as f:
    file = f.read()
        print(file)
```

In case this didn't help, try opening `videos.rstrip()` - it will remove all trailing whitespace characters, not just the `\n`.

Edit: since `videos` is an mp4 file, opening and printing it this way doesn't make much sense. Nevertheless, I'm going to leave the answer as is - some folks might face a similar problem while working with a human-readable input.
Kudos for pointing this out, @Mark Ransom!

Comment: It seems the problem was solved but raised another problem, print(file) return me non-stop binary output in terminal window.

Comment: Try replacing `'rb'` with `'r'`.

Comment: @GordonChao replacing `'rb'` with `'r'` won't help, it's almost certain to generate a `decode` error.  It simply doesn't make sense to print a video file.  There's absolutely nothing human readable in there.

Comment: @MarkRansom you're absolutely right. For some reason I forgot about the mp4 part and assumed we're dealing with a text file. Thanks!